Prove that this is an exponential function
$\newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}$
Suppose that $\on{f}:\mathbb{R}_{+}\to\mathbb{ R}_{+}$ is an increasing function:

In addition,
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty}{\on{f}\left(tx\right) \over \on{f}\left(t\right)}
\quad\mbox{exists for each}\,\, x
$$
Show that the function
$$
\on{h}\left(x\right) :=
\lim_{t \to \infty}
{\on{f}\left(tx\right) \over \on{f}\left(t\right)}
$$
is a power function in the form $x^{p}$.
What I have tried so far is to start proving properties possessed $\mbox{by}\ x^{p}$, like $\on{h}$ is increasing and
$$
\on{h}\left(xy\right) = \on{h}\left(x\right)\on{h}\left(y\right),
$$
but I got nowhere.
The major difficulty is that $\on{f}$ needs not be continuous, so I don't know where to start.


$h(x+y)=h(x)+h(y)$ is not a property of the power functions, it's a property of exponential functions. You're trying to prove $h(x)=x^p$, not $h(x) = p^x$.

The statement is incorrect. Given any increasing function $f$ having a limit $l$ at $+\infty$, $h(x) = l/f(x)$ (at least for $x > 0$). This can very well not be a power function. Maybe you want to consider $h(x) = \lim_t f(tx)/f(t)$ ?

Increasing functions are measurable. You don't need continuity, measurability is enough.

Sorry I meant exponential functions. I have edited the question.

Adding onto what was already said, I believe the way you wrote the question is filled with errors. First, if you want to show $h$ is exponential, exponential functions are of the form $h(x) = a^x$, not $h(x) = x^p$ (which are power functions). Then Rondoudou's comment still applies even if you meant exponential function. Finally, the property of exponential functions you're looking for is $h(x+y)=h(x)h(y)$.

As I pointed out in a comment above, the statement is incorrect.
However, if you define consider $f : \mathbb{R}^{+*} \to \mathbb{R}^{+*}$ such that $h(x) = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{f(tx)}{f(t)}$ exist for any $x > 0$, then you indeed have that there exist $a \geq 0$ such that $h(x) = x^a$ for all $x > 0$.
Indeed, given $x, y > 0$, you have that
$$ h(xy) = \lim_t \frac{f(txy)}{f(t)} = \lim_t \left( \frac{f(txy)}{f(tx)} \frac{f(tx)}{f(t)} \right) $$
But since both limits exist, you deduce that
$$ h(xy) = \left( \lim_t \frac{f(txy)}{f(tx)} \right) \left( \lim_t \frac{f(tx)}{f(t)} \right) = h(y) h(x) $$
Next you may prove that $h$ is increasing. Indeed, if $0 < x < y$,
$$ h(y) = \lim_t \frac{f(ty)}{f(t)} \geq \lim_t \frac{f(tx)}{f(t)} = h(x) $$
since $f$ is increasing.
Consider now the function
$$g : ~ x \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \ln(h(e^x)) $$
From what we proved, $g$ is increasing and satisfies $g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y)$. In particular, it is easy to see that $g(x) = x g(1)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. Now since $g$ is increasing, $g(1) \geq g(0) = 0$ and you can set $a = g(1)$. For any $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, you have
$$ g(x) \geq \sup_{y \in \mathbb{Q}, y \leq x} g(y) = a \sup_{y \in \mathbb{Q}, y \leq x} y = ax $$
Doing the same to bound by above, you deduce that $g(x) = ax$ for any $x$.
Finally, going back to $h$, for any $x > 0$, $h(x) = e^{g(\ln(x))} = e^{a \ln(x)} = x^a$.
(NB : you can do it without introducing $g$, but it has the advantage of reducing the matter to the simple functional equation $g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y)$ and to identify the constant $a$ easily. Also, all power functions can be obtained that way, since considering $f(x) = x^p$ gives $h(x) = x^p$ as well.)
